# Rails 4 How to assign value to dropdowns in a hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

For example I need to create a dropdown with options "Sedentary", "Lightly Active", "Active", "Very Active" and assign those to a user as an integer(0, 1,..3). How can I make a hash

```
activity_level = {"Sedentary" => 0,
                  ..............,
                  "Very Active" => 3}
```

and store an integer value instead of a string?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
f.input :fieldname, as: select, collection: activity_level.keys
```

When saving it

```
your_model_object.attribute = activity_level[params[:selected_value]]
your_model_object.save
```

Answer (score 0):

Best option IMO would be using the Rails enum feature, which maps integer to string values:

```
class Activity < AR::Base
  enum :activity_level => [ :sedentary, :lightly_active, :active, :very_active ]

  def self.activity_levels  # or store in an I18n.
     { "sedentary" => "Sedentary", "lighty_active" => "Lightly Active", ...}
  end
```

AR will store that columns internally as integer, but you have never to deal with this. You can also use the convenient query methods, like `Activity.sedentary.where...` or `if @activity.sedentary?`

And the form (When I remember correctly, the collection needs to be pairs of [v, k] not [k, v], so "Lightly Active" => "lightly_active"):

```
= f.input :activity_level, as: :select, collection: Activity.activity_levels.map(&:reverse)
```